# Django: TypeError: <MuzejskiPredmet: > is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, json

I have the following view (there is a bit more code, what to do when get or post, etc, but it's irrelevant to the problem):

```
@login_required
def muzejskipredmetadd(request):
    if not 'predmet' in request.session:
        request.session['predmet'] = MuzejskiPredmet()
    tipoviPredmeta = TipPredmeta.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("azuriranje/muzejskiPredmetForm.html",
                              {'predmet': predmet, 'tipoviPredmeta': tipoviPredmeta},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I get the error in the title. Now, the Definitive guide states that the session dictionary accepts any Python object capable of being pickled. While my `MuzejskiPredmet` class extends the django.models.Model I have no idea if that's enough for it to be considered "pickleable".

I've been reading online, and while there are plenty of examples for simple classes that have "primitive" fields, I'm not sure what to do when I have a `ForeignKey` field, or a `ManyToMany` field. How to work with those in terms of pickling?

So the whole idea behind this code is that I want to allow my user to be able to jump from this form to add new objects for the comboboxes (which contain foreignkey related objects). Once the user creates the related object (in the new form) I want to return to this one, but I don't want to get a clear form, rather the form the user left before he went off to create a new entry in the combobox, hence the need for the session attribute. Note that I'm not even sure if this will work, nor if this is the right way to handle this.

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/azuriranje/muzejski-predmet/dodavanje/

Django Version: 1.5.4
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django_tables2',
 'BackOffice')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  187.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py" in process_response
  38.                     request.session.save()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py" in save
  51.             session_data=self.encode(self._get_session(no_load=must_create)),
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py" in encode
  84.         serialized = self.serializer().dumps(session_dict)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\signing.py" in dumps
  100.         return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py" in dumps
  250.         sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py" in encode
  207.         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py" in iterencode
  270.         return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py" in default
  184.         raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Exception Type: TypeError at /azuriranje/muzejski-predmet/dodavanje/
Exception Value: <MuzejskiPredmet: > is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code causing the problem? Where are you defining `predmet`?

Comment: Well, the thing is, I created a custom form for my MuzejskiPredmet object, so that I could add a (+) button next to the fields for related objects (foreign keys, many-to-many) so that I could jump to that form, add a new entity, and return back.

Now, since I don't want my user to have to rewrite all the information I thought storing it on the session would help (though I still wasn't able to test even if this works). That being said, I place "predmet" only the first time the form is accessed, and remove it when the entity is saved (at the end, though not displayed here).

Comment: You need to show a bit more code and also explain exactly what is going on.  Start by showing the complete error message (traceback).

Comment: Ok, I've added a bit more explanation and the traceback.

Comment: Replace `request.session['predmet'] = MuzejskiPredmet()` with `request.session['predmet'] = MuzejskiPredmet.objects.create()`

Comment: What happens if the user decides to not submit the form? Won't that clutter the database with semi-filled entries?

Is there a better way to handle what I need (for the form to preserve state while the user adds external entities)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the objects represent but you could try:

```
@login_required
def muzejskipredmetadd(request):
    if not 'predmet' in request.session:
        predmet = MuzejskiPredmet()
        predmet.save()
        request.session['predmet'] = predmet.pk
    else:
        predmet = MuzejskiPremet.objects.get(pk = request.session['predmet'])
    tipoviPredmeta = TipPredmeta.objects.all()
    return render_to_response("azuriranje/muzejskiPredmetForm.html",
                              {'predmet': predmet, 'tipoviPredmeta': tipoviPredmeta},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This will save the `predmet` object to the database, and store it's primary key value to the session instead. If the primary key is already in the session, the correct object will be retrieved.

The issue with this might be that a lot of these objects could be created and stored, so a garbage collection routine might be required that deletes old objects.